# Node Referenced entity fields not showing in views?

Tags: 8, entities

I have created a content types "**author detail and blog content**".

**In which author detail is having fields**

1)author name

2)author picture

3)author designation

4)about author

Then i created a field "author details(node reference field)" in **blog content**

After creating a view block none of fields of **author details**(reference entity) is showing and also this block should be contexual filter based.

I have tried to achieve it by reading articles available on internet,Only one field is holding all the fields value ,i want to show field value in such sequence so that i can give specific class to each and every field.

1)author name

2)author picture

3)author designation

4)about author

How to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

For displaying the authors details within a Twig template see [How can you render fields from an entity reference in node templates? [Drupal 8]](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198694/how-can-you-render-fields-from-an-entity-reference-in-node-templates-drupal-8) - for creating a views block this page might help you: https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004