# How to render field of one type of node to another type node

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I have two types of nodes: `metals` and `prices`.

Metals has two fields:

```
field_gold
```

and

```
field_silver
```

How to render this fields on node--prices.html.twig (not node--metals.html.twig)

Please, help me!

Comment: what's the relationship between `metals` and `prices`, one of them refer to another ??

Comment: No, I did not make any relationship.

Comment: I think should be a relationship between the two nodes, otherwise will not know the fields of which  `metals` node should show on which `prices`.

Comment: Theoretically, if I establish a relationship between them, then it will be possible to display the field of one node in the TWIG(!!!) template of another?

Comment: Better configure in UI how to display the referenced node. For TWIG see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198694/how-can-you-render-fields-from-an-entity-reference-in-node-templates-drupal-8

Comment: yes, after you make `prices` has reference to `metals` you will need to `template_preprocess_node` to get the fields values from `metals` node and pass them to prices twig template.

Comment: Or use Views to display a contextual block showing Metal info on Prices pages, to keep things in the configuration layer and out of theme files.

Comment: @berramou I made a reference between `prices` and `metals`, but what shoud I put in `template_preprocess_node`. If you know, please help.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you made reference between `prices` and `metals` implement `hook_preprocess_node` like the following:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function MyTemplate_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->bundle() == 'prices') {
    $price_node = $variables['node'];
    //- Get reference target id
    /**
     * @TODO: change field_reference_metals by the referenced field.
     */
    $metals_node_target_id = $price_node->field_reference_metals->getValue()[0]['target_id'];

    //- Load metals referred node
    $metals_node = Node::load($metals_node_target_id);

    //- Set field_gold from metals node
    $variables['field_gold'] = $metals_node->field_gold->value;
    //- Set field_silver from metals node
    $variables['field_silver'] = $metals_node->field_silver->value;
  }
}
```

In `node--prices.html.twig` template add:

```
   {{ field_gold }}
   {{ field_silver }}
```

1. Change `MyTemplate` by your custom theme/module name.
2. Change `field_reference_metals` by the field from your prices content type referred to metals.
3. clear cache.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I did everything as you indicated, but I get an error `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Class 'Node' not found in unctema_preprocess_node() (line 59 of themes\unctema\unctema.theme).`

Comment: $metal_prices_node = Node::load($metal_prices_node_target_id);

Comment: add this `use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;`  on top of your file `unctema.theme`

Comment: Now site works, but I see error under my node - `User error: "value" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element.php).` and I do not see the value from metal fields...

Comment: Try with the edit use `->value` instead of `->getValue()` ?

Comment: `->value` works great. Thank you good man for your help. +100500 in your karma!

Comment: you are welcome.